# Perl delete newline characters from matched string

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to parse some source files and am stuck with this problem. I am searching to match a particular string which has "<<<" and ">>>" in it, and I am trying to delete all newline characters starting from when it finds the above symbols till it encounters the first ";" symbol. Any help will be much appreciated.

This is what I am trying to do:

Input:

```
... lines of code 
func1 <<< abc, xyz >>> ( str1,
                         str2,
                         str3);
... lines of code
```

Output:

```
... lines of code
func1 <<< abc, xyz >>> (str1, str2, str3);
... lines of code
```

The variables func1, abc, xyz, str1, str2, str3 can all vary.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is what I have tried and so far it only prints the same pattern as the input.

```
while (<$fh>) { 
  if (/\<\<\<.*\>\>\>/) {
     while ($_ !~ /\)\s*\;/) {
           chomp $_;
           $_ = <$fh>;
     }
     print $_;
   }
 }
```

EDIT 2:

Problem has been resolved. See answers.

Comment: If a line contains `<<< ... >>>`, then `chomp` it, and concatenate the next line. Rinse, repeat until you find a `;` at the end of the line. Done.

Comment: @TLP: I tried concatenating too. But still it doesn't work.

Comment: You are not concatenating in that code.

Comment: @TLP: I already tried something like $_ = $_.<$fh>, but it does not work.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a problem description.

Comment: I mean that currently I still get the same pattern as the input itself.

Comment: The code you have presented works as expected, with a few tweaks: Placing the print outside the if-block, and adding concatenation. If that does not work, then you have some other problem. Then you need to take a look at your input and see if there are non-printable characters messing you up, or some such.

Answer (score 3):

```
my @long, $end;
while (<>) {                               # read a line
  if (/<<<.*>>>/ .. ($end = /;/)) {        # if needs joining,
    s/^\s+|\s+$//g;                        # trim it
    push @long, $_;                        # add to list
    print join(' ', @long) . "\n" if $end; # paste and print if at end
  } else {                                 # if doesn't need joining,
    print;                                 # just print without changes
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
perl -npe 'if (/<<<.*?>>>/../;/) { chomp unless /;/ }' filename
```

Here's what it does:

1. Loop through all lines in the file (the -n option)
2. Match all lines between (and including) `<<<.*?>>>` and `;` and remove newlines from those. This is not done for the line containing `;`.
3. Print all the lines (the -p option)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking compressing a statement that contains `<<<` and as far as `;`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    if ( m/<<</ .. m/\);$/ ) {
         s/\s+/ /g;
         s/;\s*$/;\n/g;
    }
    print;
}

__DATA__
... lines of code 
func1 <<< abc, xyz >>> ( str1,
                         str2,
                         str3);
... lines of code
```

- We use the range operator to detect if we are between `<<<` and `\);$`
- if we are, we replace whitespace and linefeeds with single spaces.
- And we do then need to reinsert the trailing linefeed after the `;`

This outputs:

```
... lines of code 
func1 <<< abc, xyz >>> ( str1,  str2,  str3);
... lines of code
```